How to literally translate this: 伊朗人没有触及我们空军的能力——没有（以方）飞机受损，没有一个飞行中队失序
每日经济新闻 2024-10-06 23:33 (Beijing time)
每经编辑 杜宇
据参考消息援引法新社10月6日报道，以色列国防部长约亚夫·加兰特6日警告伊朗，如果后者企图伤害以色列，“它可能最终看来更像加沙或贝鲁特”。
加兰特在一份声明中说：“伊朗人没有触及我们空军的能力——没有（以方）飞机受损，没有一个飞行中队失序。”他指的是伊朗最近对以色列发动的导弹袭击。那次袭击的目标包括以色列的两个空军基地。
...
I want your help in the literal translation of this:
伊朗人没有触及我们空军的能力——没有（以方）飞机受损，没有一个飞行中队失序。

没有 is like the present perfect in English? have not? 没有触及 = have not touched, 没有受损 = have not been damaged, 没有失序 = have not disordered??? Something like that?

What means 触及能力？To touch ability? How can an ability be touched? It doesn't make sense to me.

What is the meaning of ——? Just a meaningless point? Why is it used there?




伊朗人没有触及我们空军的能力——没有（以方）飞机受损，没有一个飞行中队失序。


伊朗人 -  The Iranians

没有 - do not have

触及我们空军的能力 - the ability to touch our Air Force (the ability to reach and attack our Air Force)


(touch --> reach -->attack -->)

—— is for emphasis. It is like a brief pause in a speech —— for dramatic effect

没有（以方）飞机受损 - No (Israeli) aircraft is damaged

没有一个飞行中队失序 - Not a squadron broke formation (meaning no Iranian airplane affected their operation in any way)


Notice:
没有能力 = do not have + noun
没有受损 = not + verb
没有失序 = not + verb

没有：no, not
触及：touch (here: harm)
空军：airforce
能力：ability
受损：be damaged
中队：squadron
失序：不工作，损坏: out of order, damaged
伊朗人没有触及我们空军的能力
The Iranians do not have the ability to harm our airforce
——没有（以方）飞机受损，
no (Israeli) airplane was damaged,
没有一个飞行中队失序。
not one squadron missed a step.

触及 may mean 到达
失序 is not a usual word in everyday Chinese
My understanding of the whole:
The capability of our air force is out of reach of Iranian (missiles)--They failed to damage any of our planes or to make any squadrons in disorder.

伊朗人没有触及我们空军的能力——没有（以方）飞机受损，没有一个飞行中队失序。
Iranians do not have the capability to touch(触及) our Airforce——There is no Iseral's(以方）airplane was damaged, and there is no squadron in disarray(失序 means something has "lost its original order", which indicating a chaotic condition).
